# Angular 2 TypeError: zone.addTask

Tags: angular

I have some code witch just stop working... and I don't have any idea why.

HTML:

```
<a class="nav_link" [routerLink]="['RowList']">
    <svg><use xlink:href="#icon-list"></use></svg>
    Lista
</a>
```

JS:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/UI/row/list', component: RowList, name: 'RowList'}
])
```

And it works fine until last Friday (*29.01.2016*), now in console:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: zone.addTask is not a function
```

I have ZoneJS in my project.

---

**[EDIT]**

Stack trace:

> TypeError: zone.addTask is not a function
>       at Zone.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:11297:28)
>       at Zone.setTimeout (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:26201:27)
>       at window.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:11263:47)
>       at SafeSubscriber. (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:23249:63)
>       at SafeSubscriber.tryCatcher [as _next] (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:23899:32)
>       at SafeSubscriber.next (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:23852:19)
>       at EventEmitter.Subject._finalNext (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:23450:31)
>       at EventEmitter.Subject._next (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:23442:19)
>       at EventEmitter.Subject.next (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:23405:15)
>       at EventEmitter.emit (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:23239:77)
>
> -----async gap----- Error
>       at _getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:11857:30)
>       at Zone.fork (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:11906:48)
>       at Zone.bind (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:10833:54)
>       at bindArguments (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:11016:37)
>       at lib$es6$promise$promise$$Promise.obj.(anonymous function) [as then] (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:11028:47)
>       at lib$es6$promise$promise$$Promise.catch (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:10680:23)
>       at lib$es6$promise$promise$$Promise.obj.(anonymous function) [as catch] (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:11028:35)
>       at Function.PromiseWrapper.catchError (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:23293:30)
>       at RootRouter.Router._afterPromiseFinishNavigating (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:42623:40)
>       at http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:42558:27
>
> -----async gap----- Error
>       at _getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:11857:30)
>       at Zone.fork (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:11906:48)
>       at Zone.bind (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:10833:54)
>       at bindArguments (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:11016:37)
>       at lib$es6$promise$promise$$Promise.obj.(anonymous function) [as then] (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:11028:47)
>       at RootRouter.Router.navigateByUrl (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:42555:67)
>       at new RootRouter (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:42819:15)
>       at routerFactory (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:42380:23)
>       at Injector._instantiate (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:14048:28)
>       at Injector._instantiateProvider (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:13996:26)
>
> -----async gap----- Error
>       at *getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:11857:30)
>       at Zone.fork (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:11906:48)
>       at Zone.bind (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:10833:54)
>       at bindArguments (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:11016:37)
>       at lib$es6$promise$promise$$Promise.obj.(anonymous function) [as then] (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:11028:47)
>       at DynamicComponentLoader*.loadAsRoot (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:26563:52)
>       at di_1.provide.useFactory (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:25405:48)
>       at Injector._instantiate (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:14045:28)
>       at Injector._instantiateProvider (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:13996:26)
>       at Injector._new (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:13985:22)
>
> -----async gap----- Error
>       at _getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:11857:30)
>       at Zone.fork (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:11906:48)
>       at NgZone.*createInnerZone (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:26128:15)
>       at new NgZone (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:25914:37)
>       at createNgZone (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:25428:13)
>       at PlatformRef*.application (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:25529:34)
>       at Object.bootstrap (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:12022:65)
>       at HTMLDocument.main (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:56780:23)
>       at Zone.run (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:10858:25)
>       at HTMLDocument.zoneBoundFn (http://localhost:8081/prod/scripts.gz.js:10835:27)

Comment: Which version of Angular2 do you use?

Comment: I starts with `angular@2.0.0-beta.0` but even I upgrade `angular` to `2.0.0-beta.2` with all libs, it still not worked

Comment: Okay. Do you have any hints about where the error occurs?

Comment: I edit question and add stack trace

Comment: Thanks! Do you use zones explicitly through `NgZone`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the **zone.js** dependency (version 0.5.10) and I can't see any `addTask` method in the `Zone` object (see file `node_modules/zone.js/lib/zones/core.js`).

Do you use explicitly zones in your Angular application through `NgZone`?

**Edit**

In Angular2, ZoneJs is provided within the `node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js` file.

Thierry

Comment: No, I just imports `zone.js/dist/zone-microtask` and `zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone`. When I start create this app I cue from `https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter`

Comment: Perhaps you could try to use the file: angular2-polyfills.js. It contains zonejs and reflect-metadata... I updated my answer...